# Azure Function app logging custom properties in Application Insights

Tags: .net, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I'm using .net 6 with a ServiceBusTrigger Azure Function app.    I'm using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger from inside my function app to log Trace messages to Application Insights.  That works fine.  e.g.

`_logger.LogInformation("Hello World")`

But I'd like to get some custom properties to be included too. I tried

`System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current.AddBaggage()` but Current it's always null.

So i tried BeginScope like so and that doesn't work either.

```
                object customProps = new
                {
                    OrderNumber = "something",
                    TransactionType = transactionType,
                };

                using (_logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object> { 
                    ["CustomerId"] = 12345)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("abc ");
                    _logger.LogInformation("def  {properties}", customProps);
                }
```

Then I tried using the second parm on the LogInformation method and that doesn't work either.

`_logger.LogInformation("xyz {properties}", customProps);`

The message is logged, it just doesn't have any custom properties.

Does anyone have any ideas to try?   I'm not using any application insight nuget packages at the moment.  Just the default ILogger.  I've also tried dotnet-isolated and non isolated.

-Randy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created service bus queue trigger function with runtime stack dotnet.

I have created service bus queue and sent a message from service bus explorer.

**Function Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp8121
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        private readonly TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;

        [Obsolete]
        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger, IConfiguration config)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _config = config;
            string instrumentationKey = _config["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"];
            _telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(new TelemetryConfiguration(instrumentationKey));
        }

        [Function(nameof(Function1))]
        [Obsolete]
        public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("firstqueue", Connection = "servicebusconnection")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Message ID: {id}", message.MessageId);
            _logger.LogInformation("Message Body: {body}", message.Body);
            _logger.LogInformation("Message Content-Type: {contentType}", message.ContentType);

            // Log custom events to Application Insights
            _telemetryClient.TrackEvent("MessageProcessed", new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "MessageID", message.MessageId },
                { "MessageType", message.ContentType },
            });

            // Log custom properties
            var properties = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "FirstName", "pavan" },
                { "LastName", "kumar" },
            };

            _telemetryClient.TrackTrace("User Details", SeverityLevel.Information, properties);

            // Track custom metric
            _telemetryClient.TrackMetric("CustomMetric", 42);

            // Automatically flush telemetry data to Application Insights (no need for manual Flush)
        }
    }
}
```

**local.settings.json:**

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "servicebusconnection": "your-servicebus connection string",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey": "your instrumentation key"

  }
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

I am getting the logs in application insights check below:

[image]

I am able to get the custom properties. Check below:

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  The key was using a new TelemetryClient vs the ILogger.  Thanks!